# Check if CGRect null in getter

Tags: ios, ios6, null, cgrect, cgrectmake

I am trying to check if a `CGRect` is `null` in my property getter and if it is, load a value by default, however, in my init method, when I use the property, it returns zero for all values.

Here is my getter:

```
- (CGRect)frame
{
    if(CGRectIsNull(_frame))
        _frame = CGRectMake(0,0,60,60);
    return _frame;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:self.frame];
    if(self)
    {
        //do something
    }
    return self;
}
```

I am not sure what's going on and where to look. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

When you create an instance of your class, the `_frame` instance variable is automatically initialized, even before the `init` method is called. Since `_frame` is a C-struct (`CGRect`), its memory is cleared to all zeroes. This results in a `CGRect` with all zero values.

`CGRectNull` is a special, non-zero `CGRect`. So your check using `CGRectIsNull()` will never be true.

Using `CGRectIsEmpty` is a more proper check for this.

Comment: `CGRectIsEmpty` is the better way to go here, but I think it's worth mentioning that you could also use `CGRectEqualToRect` and compare to `CGRectZero`

Comment: True but using `CGRectIsEmpty(_frame)` is shorter than `CGRectEqualToRect(_frame, CGRectZero)`.

Comment: It is, and CGRectIsEmpty would be my preference as well, just pointing it out :)

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my issue! I'm new to objective-c and iOS, so learning the libraries and methods that are available to me will come with time. I have pretty strong google-fu, but this one stumped me pretty good. Thanks again!

Comment: @rmaddy sorry about that - just did.

Answer (score 12):

Try

```
- (CGRect)frame
{
    if (CGRectIsEmpty(_frame)) 
    _frame = CGRectMake(0,0,60,60);

    return _frame;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an updated answer for Swift 4. You are able to simply use CGRect's `isNull` boolean property to check for CGRectNull now:

```
let someRect = CGRect.null
print(someRect.isNull) // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, one needs to understand that a null rectangle and a rectangle which have zero width and height is different.

In Swift 5.0 and above-

To check whether a rectangle is null or not - use the `isNull` property on the rectangle. Let's say the rectangle variable's identifier is 'myFrame'. Then do following-

```
if !myFrame.isNull{
    //do sth if the frame is not nul
}
```

And for a rectangle of .zero(width = 0, height = 0) frame, check in following way -

```
if !myFrame.isEmpty{
    // do sth is the frame has height or width
}
```